# How to refresh div without refreshing the entire site with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to refresh a table by button click.

I searched around and found this.

```
$("#Table2").load(location.href + " #Table2");
```

That works perfectly if I use a older version of jQuery. But in newer versions of jQuery, it does not work anymore.

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
```

In jQuery 3.0 they removed it and changed it.
If I follow their documentation and change it to

```
$("#Table2").on("load", location.href + " #Table2");
```

I would get this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string

Can someone help me figure out how to refresh a div

Comment: The original version still works in 3x.  The *event binding format*, which is your second format, is the version that was removed in 3x.  https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: More specifically, 3x removed the evaluation of if it should do an ajax load, or if it should make an event binding.  It always does an ajax load now.

Comment: I get the error message in console saying 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

Comment: Specifically which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the slim edition of jQuery. Using the regular version fixed it.